# Adding more columns, even when the table looks full

Tags: data-tables, ux-designer, user-feedback

At the moment we have a prototype of a table which shows a list of car rentals.

However, the clients want to add more columns, like add car registration number and another 2 columns more, but I felt it could be squashing the table. Is there a way to have all columns in one table without looking squashed or overcrowded. We need something easy to read and less complex for them.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the columns are important to the business and provide useful information, one option to free up some room is to simplify the way you're presenting the date range.

[image]
This can make it more readable, and you now have some extra space.

Another option is to have the big <kbd>View</kbd> button appear on hover, and save another column.

Comment: Thanks for this, it’s look good and easy to read on ‘duration’ column and yes it does gives a more extra space on the table.